# pytest unable to mock the same module multiple times

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm tring to use mock to test a specific function, for some reasons it seems that I can't mock twice the same module and I don't understand why

a.py

```
def a():
    return "ok"
```

b.py

```
    from sandbox.tests.a import a
    
    
    def b(la):
    
        for i in la:
            a()
    
        return "b"
    
    
    def c():
        a()
        return "c"
```

What I want to test is the amount of calls of *a* are made, so in my test I do :

```
    from mock import patch
    
    
    @patch("sandbox.tests.a.a", return_value="mocked")
    def test_b(mock):
        from sandbox.tests.b import b
    
        b(["1", "2"])
    
        assert mock.call_count == 2
    
    
    @patch("sandbox.tests.a.a", return_value="mocked2")
    def test_b_again(mock):
        from sandbox.tests.b import c
    
        c()
    
        assert mock.call_count == 1
```

If I run 1 test it works but when I run the 2 tests together I have this error :

```
E       AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
E        +  where 0 = <Mock name='test_2' id='4360227664'>.call_count
```

Surprisingly if I print the output of the mock in each function b and c, the mock has the same ID :

```
a <MagicMock name='a' id='4358021024'> # function b
a <MagicMock name='a' id='4358021024'> # function c
```

I also tried to put a name on the mock but it stills gives the same id

```
@patch("sandbox.tests.a.a")
def test_b(mock):
    mock = Mock(name="test_1", return_value="test_1")
    from sandbox.tests.b import b

    b(["1", "2"])

    assert mock.call_count == 2


@patch("sandbox.tests.a.a")
def test_b_again(mock):
    mock = Mock(name="test_2", return_value="test_2")
    from sandbox.tests.b import c

    c()

    assert mock.call_count == 1
```

Is there an equivalent of jest.resetModules() or something so I can mock twice the same module ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to patch `a` within the context of module `b`, rather than trying to patch `sandbox.tests.a` 'directly'. This is necessary because module `b` imports `a` only once, rather than in each of functions `b` and `c`.

Instead, patch `sandbox.tests.b.a` - i.e the 'instance' of `a` which is being used by module `b`:

```
@patch("sandbox.tests.b.a", return_value="mocked")
def test_b(self, mock):
    from sandbox.tests.b import b
    
    b(["1", "2"])
    
    assert mock.call_count == 2
    
    
@patch("sandbox.tests.b.a", return_value="mocked2")
def test_c(self, mock):
    from sandbox.tests.b import c

    c()
    assert mock.call_count == 1
```

Comment: Works as a charm, very interesting I didn't know about this module context in python. Thanks